# Is async lambda legal in typescript and upcoming ecmascript 7?

Tags: typescript, async-await, arrow-functions, ecmascript-next

These are two related questions:

1. Is async lambda legal in upcoming EcmaSript standard?
2. TypeScript follows EcmaScript, and compiler used to complain about `async () => { await whatever(); }`, and now, with version 1.8, it does not. Is the new behavior intended, or is it a bug?

If ES will allow for async lambda, then TS naturally follows the suite.
But, if ES will not support async lambda, will TS properly place this->that substitutions in future code? After all, async lambda exists in C#.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, [the proposal](https://tc39.github.io/ecmascript-asyncawait/#async-function-definitions) currently does cover `async` arrow functions, and it's unlikely to change that.

Comment: Yey! async all the way!